# How to disable range of time in Kendo datetime picker javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

How to rage of time in kendo datetime picker exapmle: 
disable time range 03.01.2019 10:00am - 03.01.2019 10:30am

```
   $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    value: new Date(),
    dateInput: true,
    format: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm",
    interval: 5,
    timeFormat: "HH:mm",
    min: new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd + 1, HH, MM, 0),
    disableDates:[]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you might consider using [DatePicker](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index) instead of [DateTimePicker](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create DatePicker from input HTML element
  $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    value: new Date(),
    dateInput: true,
    format: "MM/dd/yyyy"
  });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: he is asking how to disable a specific range of time, not all.